# google translate and bing translate APIs working in production but not on development localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, google-translate

Can anyone help me figure out why the google translate and bing translate APIs are working in production but not in development on my laptop?

Google's error: "bad request"

Bing's error: "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to reinstall openssl.